# How to get order of reordered elements

Tags: jquery, indexing, element

i have a problem about getting order of my divs.

Scenario : i have a structure like this :

```
<div class="container">
<div class="element" id="element1">
<div class="element" id="element2">
<div class="element" id="element3">
<div class="element" id="element4">
```

but i am re-ordering / deleteing / adding some elements related to some conditions
So suppose that final structure like this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="element" id="element6">
<div class="element" id="element2">
<div class="element" id="element8">
<div class="element" id="element4">
<div class="element" id="element1">
<div class="element" id="element7">
```

and finally i want to get a list of elements in final order
I'am using

```
var ord= '';
for (i=1;i<=($('.element').length);i++){
  var index = $('#element'+i).index();
  ord+= index+' / ';
}
```

but it gives me the indexes of elements in creation order, not final order.
Finally, i think that i need to get the item id from its index like

```
var index = indexof($('#element'+i)); // ok this is not lookink like correct :)
```

But no way i found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="element" id="element6">1</div>
    <div class="element" id="element2">2</div>
    <div class="element" id="element8">3</div>
    <div class="element" id="element4">4</div>
    <div class="element" id="element1">5</div>
    <div class="element" id="element7">6</div>
</div>
```

and this javascript:

```
var arr = Array();
$('.container .element').each(function(){
   arr.push($(this).attr('id').replace('element', ''));
})
```

you get this:

```
arr = ["6", "2", "8", "4", "1", "7"]
```

Answer (score 3):

for this markup (the reordered elements...):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="element" id="element4"></div>
    <div class="element" id="element1"></div>
    <div class="element" id="element5"></div>
    <div class="element" id="element6"></div>
    <div class="element" id="element7"></div>
</div>
```

the $('.container').find('.element') command will produce the elements in the order as they appear on the document.

```
elements = $('.container').find('.element')
console.log(elements[0].id) // will print out 'element4'
console.log(elements[2].id) // ---> 'element5'
```

and so on....

to get the numerical id out of the 'elementX' string just do

```
parseInt(elements[3].id.replace('element','')) // will return 6
```

Comment: nice solution but I think you forgot the .id after elements[3].id.replace(etc

Answer (score 1):

I think you're better off just creating an array of N elements and initializing it with the starting order of the divs. Then, every time you swap elements and change their order you update the array by swapping the corresponding elements and just read the array every time to get the current order.

For example, let's say you have 10 elements, you initialize the array with:

```
order = new Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
```

Every time you do some reordering, let's say you swap element number X with element number Y you also swap the corresponding array elements:

```
swap(order, X, Y);
```

(You'll have to define a swap function, by the way).
So the `order` array will contain the current order at every time.